# Node.js Module - Ninja-Labs/Verify-pdf shows digital signature Verified-false for PDF Signature Validation

Tags: node.js, validation, digital-signature

Digital Signature is Valid with All root Certificates in Adobe Reader but still showing False & undefined for Verified,Authenticity,Integrity,Expired ?

Anyone have solutions or any other options will be helpful. Thanks In advance.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const verifyPDF = require('@ninja-labs/verify-pdf');
const { getCertificatesInfoFromPDF } = require('@ninja-labs/verify-pdf');
var d='C://Users//xxxxxx//Downloads//Testss.pdf';
const signedPdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(d);
const {
    verified,
    authenticity,
    integrity,
    expired,
    meta
} = verifyPDF(signedPdfBuffer);
const certs = getCertificatesInfoFromPDF(signedPdfBuffer);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("PDF FILE NAME ----",d);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("verified ----",verified);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("authenticity ----",authenticity);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("integrity ----",integrity);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("expired ----",expired);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("certs ----",certs);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
''''
```

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis. Adobe Acrobat is very lax when validating signatures cryptographically and ignores several errors.